# XCode CI stuck running the UITests (Uploading 10 screenshots for -[AppTests textExample])

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ui-testing

The problem is, when CI Server makes the Bot integration for the first time all (UI and UNIT) tests run fine but on second integration the server stuck with this status:

[image]

and I can't cancel integration, can't stop the process, every time on second integration I need to remove the bot and create new one.

Working with last macOS Server XCode 8 and iPhone 7 Simulator on iOS, I have tried another simulators, nothing changed.

This happen if I have UITest, with UNIT Tests all runs fine.

Comment: FWIW, we have exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution in the past month?

Comment: @Epaga Not yet, waiting for updates from apple. This happen only on our old imac 2009 with core duo cpu.

Comment: See my answer. That would explain your problems. Ours is a Mac Mini 2010, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/steipete/status/793360856671260672) by @steipete:

Known Issues, Xcode 8.2:

```
“Simulator_app shows a black screen when booting simulated
devices on macOS that do not support Metal.“
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html

The only computers that support Metal are:

- MacBook (Early 2015)
- MacBook Air (Mid 2012 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 or newer)
- Mac mini (Late 2012 or newer)
- iMac (Late 2012 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013 or newer)

(https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205073)

So if your computer is older, this seems to be causing those issues.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, but was able to solve it just checking my tests code.

The test bundle was crashing (in my case due to an implicitly unwrapped optional as I was expecting an environmental variable to be defined).

You can download the logs clicking on the *Download Logs...* button.

[image: Download Xcode log]

There I was able to find the exception and solve the issue.

Comment: These builds never finish, there are no Logs to Download